# FadeInImage with Firebase Storage only working once

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to create a simple fadein for an image with `FadeInImage.memoryNetwork`
The image loads from FB Storage and after that it should fade in.
The problem is, that it works only once. If it was already loaded, the second time it is simply displayed - without fadein.

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shimmer_animation/shimmer_animation.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';


class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final TestModel test;

  const Item({super.key, required this.test});

  @override
  State<Item> createState() => _ItemState();
}

class _ItemState extends State<Item> {
  String? _imageUrl;
  bool _loaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getImageUrl("image", widget.test.image);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  Future getImageUrl(type, name) async {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(type).child(name);

    await ref.getDownloadURL().then(_setImageData).catchError((err) {
      _setError();
    });
  }

  _setImageData(dynamic url) async {
    // NetworkImage image = NetworkImage(url);

    if (mounted) {
      //await precacheImage(image, context);

      setState(() {
        _loaded = true;
        _imageUrl = url;
      });
    }
  }

  _setError() {
    setState(() {
      _loaded = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        height: 80,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                offset: const Offset(2.0, 4.0),
                blurRadius: 8),
          ],
        ),

        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(children: [
          AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 8,
              child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
                Shimmer(
                  child: Container(
                    // height: 120,
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                  ),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  colorOpacity: 0.5,
                  enabled: true,
                  direction: ShimmerDirection.fromLTRB(),
                ),
                if (_imageUrl != null)
                  FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                      // key: UniqueKey(),
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                      image: _imageUrl!,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover),
              
     
              ]))
        ]));
  }
}
```

how to make the image always fade in, even if I previously retrieve the url from firebase?